# Why is 019 not a JavaScript syntax error? Or why is 019 > 020

Tags: javascript, grammar, language-lawyer, ecmascript-5, javacc

If I type `019 > 020` in the JavaScript console (tested in both Chrome and Firefox), I get the answer `true`.

This is due to `020` being interpreted as an [`OctalIntegerLiteral`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1) (equals `16`) whereas `019` is apparently being interpreted as [`DecimalLiteral`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) (and equals `19`). As `19` is greater than `16`, `019 > 020` is `true`.

What puzzles me is why `019` is interpreted as a `DecimalLiteral` in first place. Which production is it? `DecimalIntegerLiteral` does not allow `019`:

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits_opt
```

`OctalIntegerLiteral` also does not allow `019` (as `9` is not an octal digit):

```
OctalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit
    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit

OctalDigit :: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

So from what I see in the specification, `019` should actually be rejected, I don't see why it is interpreted as a decimal integer.

I guess there's some kind of compatibility rule in place here but I have failed to find a formal definition. Could please anyone help me with this?

(Why I need this: I'm developing a [JavaScript/ECMAScript parser for Java with JavaCC](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel) and have to pay a special attention to the specification - and deviations thereof.)

Comment: Could it be the left argument gets treated as a string, and (therefore) so does the right argument -- *after* being converted to a decimal?

Comment: @Jongware No, it's not inside any quotes so not a string.

Comment: JavaScript is pretty forgiving. Maybe it just converts the `019` by trimming the excess zeros.

Comment: But you don't get any error... hm. What is `019+1`?

Comment: `019 + 0 == 19` and `020 + 0 == 17` so it's ignoring the leading zero if it contains non Octal digits.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini This is what I'm saying. The question is *why* of *if* is it formally correct.

Comment: Fun fact: `'use strict'; 019` → SyntaxError: octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated

Comment: @lexicore this is a specific parsing issue. You're looking for the specifications of how JavaScript will interrupt a literal as Octal. Not sure where that would be documented.

Comment: @Mathew: surely `020 + 0 ≠≠ 17` :)

Comment: @René Interesting. `019` is actually *not* an octal literal as far as I can tell.

Comment: @lexicore, also interesting: `parseInt("020", 8)` = 16, while `parseInt("019", 8)` = 1. [mdn - parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @Mouser: not the same thing, parseInt just stops at the first invalid character.

Comment: @FelixKling Because that's how the production is formulated. Either `0` or `NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits_opt`. If `0` is followed by anything, it's not `DecimalIntegerLiteral` anymore.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't read it correctly. FYI, `019` throws an error in esprima.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From what I could find, it seems that some implementations of JavaScript just don't follow the spec on that point.

From the [MDN site:](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Numeric_literals)

> Note that decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by
>   another decimal digit, but If the next digit after the leading 0 is
>   smaller than 8, the number gets parsed as an octal number. This won't
>   throw in JavaScript, see [bug 957513](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=957513). See also the page about
>   parseInt().

This still doesn't explain why `019 == 19`, given that the next digit after the leading 0 is 1 and the whole number should therefore be parsed as octal. But the referenced bug does seem related to your case. Its description says:

> The following JavaScript program should throw an error:
>
> ```
> 08
> ```
>
> As per the spec, `DecimalIntegerLiteral` can never be `0` directly
>   followed by another decimal digit, although Chrome/Opera, PrestOpera,
>   and Firefox do support it.

The bug is closed as WONTFIX

However, `019` would be a valid decimal literal, with value equal to 19, according to the draft of the next edition:

https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-additional-syntax-numeric-literals

(I've marked the relevant rules)

```
The syntax and semantics of 11.8.3 is extended as follows except that 
this extension is not allowed for strict mode code:

[...]

DecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0
    NonZeroDigit DecimalDigits_opt
    NonOctalDecimalIntegerLiteral                         // (1)

NonOctalDecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 NonOctalDigit
    LegacyOctalLikeDecimalIntegerLiteral NonOctalDigit    // (2)
    NonOctalDecimalIntegerLiteral DecimalDigit

LegacyOctalLikeDecimalIntegerLiteral ::
    0 OctalDigit                                          // (3)
    LegacyOctalLikeDecimalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
```

So `01` is a `LegacyOctalLikeDecimalIntegerLiteral` (3) . Then `019` is a `NonOctalDecimalIntegerLiteral` (2) which in turn is a `DecimalIntegerLiteral` (1).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Chrome seems to have a similar problem. Evaluating `019` with Spidermonkey yields `1: warning: 09 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant: 019`. It seems like it was backed out because existing (important) sites would break.

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect `019` to be an octal literal just because the second digit is a `1`? Surely anything that contains a `9` can't be octal…

Comment: @Bergi I guess you should ask the guys at MDN about that, as I couldn't find any point in the ECMAScript spec that justifies this interpretation.

Comment: Looking at V8 parsing scanner, it indeed assumes that if a number starts with 0 but has a digit 8 or 9, then the number is decimal (there is no comment explaining why though) https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/97757e2d8c5b706f1f642340a424b38e20022a2c/src/scanner.cc#L834

Comment: @VitaliiFedorenko Very impressed how you digged it out.